# WS-FEDERATION Update Certificate

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs, openam, ws-federation

Good morning fellas !!

I have a question regarding WS-FEDERATION.

We have a partner (IDP initiated and SP Hosted) that is configured with WS-FEDERATION.
They use ADFS and we use OPENAM (we are the SP)

Everything is set up fine and running smoothly.

But their certificate is going to expire soon and we have to update it.

So from what I saw here what we are suppose to do :

Export the SP and IDP metadata , replace the X509 Certificate value with the new one then import those configuration back.

Is that correct ?

I am using OPENAM, and they have the ssoadm command mapped with a GUI.

So I exported both of those metadata, I replaced the certificate value and we will re-import them with the partner at the same time.

I never did that change, and I want to make sure that it is the proper way and that I am not missing anything !

Thank you for the help :) :)

Answer (score 0):

In this situation you will find that ADFS has interim phases i.e.

- Old certificate
- Old and new
- New

During the middle phase, you need to get the ADFS metadata and re-import into OpenAM.

That way there will be no down time as both certificates are catered for.

If you wait until the third phase, there will be some downtime until you have done the new import.